# Block Calender on Jquery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using **Jquery UI Datepicker** like below in **Asp.net MVC** Application.

**Question**

1. How to **block or remove calender** ? (I don't need it)
2. Still **I want** other stuff on that Datepicker. Such as **date format,default date**, etc

**Reason**

**Not Allow** user to select a date from calender.But Need to maintain date format.

**HTML**

```
<td>
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CheckIn.DateCheckIn)
</td>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
 $('#CheckIn_DateCheckIn').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'm/d/yy', altFormat: 'yy-m-d',  onSelect: function () { $(this).parents('form:first').submit(); } });
```

**UI**

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. You don't want a datepicker, but you want to keep it? Actually, isn't your question: "how can I restrict a field to contains only a date ?"

Comment: @SteveB actually I need to remove drop down calender.

Comment: @Sampath: the drop down calendar is the essence of the datapicker plugin. If you want a textbox that accepts only date, don't use this plugin, but any validation framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of "disabling" the calendar part is to set [showOn](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn) to `"button"`:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ showOn: "button" });
```

And then just hide the button with css:

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger { display: none; }​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ukHLT/

---

Or just set the disabled html attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CheckIn.DateCheckIn, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: can I set a default date on that text box and put as readonly text ?

Comment: do you know how to disable the datepicker text box ?

Comment: @Sampath I mean the code for the CheckIn_DateCheckIn. Are you using `@Html.TextBox` or plain html (`<input type="text" .. />`)?

Comment: @Sampath Well, you could change to using `TextBoxFor` instead of `EditorFor` and set the html attributes like this: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CheckIn.DateCheckIn, new { disabled = "disabled" })`.

Comment: Thanks Mario for your invaluable support.

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
```

removed the #datepicker from the jquery code.that's it.or removed above full jquery code

Used bellow code if you want to used default date and disable it from the user

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" value="12/19/2012" id="datepicker" disabled></p>
```

[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/QmvwN/)

Comment: When I remove jquery code date format of the text also lost.Is there any other way to remove only the drop down calender ?

Comment: what do you expect from this ? ( i'm also srilankan)

Comment: So do you want when user add their date it will show using any date format right ? ex:YYYY/MMMM/DDDD

Comment: can I set a default date on that text box and put as readonly text ?

Comment: u can set the value and disable the field using jquery

Comment: <p>Date: <input type="text" value="12/19/2012" id="datepicker" disabled></p>

Comment: I edited my code and added the code what do you expert from us

Comment: +1 for your support sami. But I cannot remove date picker.B'cos need to keep specified date format for the text box.I sorted out my problem from @Mario.Thanks again for your valuable effort.

Answer (score 0):

I just Followed What **@Mario** said.

Now My Text box **having Date Format** and also **cannot select a date**.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CheckIn.DateCheckIn, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```